# Determine libuv thread pool size at runtime?

Tags: threadpool, libuv

I know that we can control the libuv thread pool size by setting the UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE environment variable before running the process in question.

However, since this may change (ex depending on server config) it would be nice to inspect the thread pool size that libuv is actually using, at runtime. How can we do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Thread pool size will not change. If you want the current value, why don't use getenv or uv_os_getenv?

Comment: Well, just noticed that @blackgreen deleted my post which had significant more information and links to facts. On the 'supposed' basis of duplication!? What duplication? My answer has a dozen paragrphs, while other answers have ONE!

Answer (score 1):

The thread pool size cannot currently change at runtime. The first time an operation is queued on the pool libuv will read the `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE` environment variable and create the thread pool. From then on its size won't change.

Comment: I know that the size is fixed, but UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE is just an environment variable, and is not fixed. This value may have changed too late (i.e. after an operation has been queued on the pool) and may not reflect the actual thread pool size being used...

Comment: Good point. At the moment the thread pool is an implementation detail which is not exposed to the outside (modulo that env variable) so adding a way to get its size won't help you because you cannot change it or do anything about it. There is a (now stalled) plan to switch to an "elastic" thread pool: https://github.com/libuv/libuv/issues/267 which would make this metric even less relevant. Why is it you need to know this at runtime?

Comment: I wrote a C++ node module addon that can be loaded by node processes that I have no control over. It would be useful if, in the module, I can inspect the libuv thread pool size to help decide on how I can behave most efficiently. I can't rely on UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE since it is known that some devs set this in their node script, but too late to have any effect.